# Why some Microsoft Azure services are marked as (classic) in Azure Portal?

Tags: azure

I see some Microsoft Azure services are marked as (classic) in Azure Portal, such as OS images, VMs, and Storage account.

Does it mean they're planned to deprecated or what? Where to find the modern services correspond to them?

Answer (score 9):

The new Azure Resource Manager (which uses a new API) spins up resources in a slightly different way than the old API's did. The classic API stack is still operational, but you'll see those resources show up in the new (Ibiza) portal as *classic*, including virtual machines, vm images, storage, OS disks, reserved IP addresses, and virtual networks (based on what I can see in the portal right now; I don't have insight into what will show up or be removed in the future).

Comment: Is there a migration path?

Comment: No there is not - Some good info here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-classic-rm/

Answer (score 2):

**Resource Manager:** This is the newest deployment model for Azure resources. Most newer resources already support this deployment model and eventually all resources will.

**Classic:** This model is supported by most existing Azure resources today. New resources added to Azure will not support this model.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-classic-rm/